# Get latest delta token for a mail folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Is there a way to get the latest delta token for a mail folder, using the Graph API?

I couldn't find documentation for this particular use case. I could find docs for the same thing, but for OneDrive. Using that as a template, I tried using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages/delta?$deltaToken=latest`. Calling the previous endpoint does return `@odata.deltaLink`, but it's not the latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$deltatoken=latest` pattern is only supported for directory resources (users, groups, service principal, applications...) as stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#use-delta-query-to-track-changes-in-a-resource-collection). It is supported for drive items with `token=latest`. (not the different query string parameter name)

Comment: It does work for drives though. E.g. something like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta?token=latest does give the latest token.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this option is not given for the mail resource type. I was also seeking for the same to pull only new emails only.

We need to traverse through all pages to get the latest delta token. Microsoft's team should consider supporting this in the future.